# XML Removing Duplicates and SUM some values to the main ones

Tags: c#, xml

Well I need some help, I have one XML file that has multiple entries, and some of them are duplicated, the problem is that I can't just delete the duplicated ones, I need to delete them but I need to sum the values of some nodes to the entry that will not be removed. 
At the moment I have the following working code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
        {
            var xml = @"
    <Sales>
  <Invoice>
    <Hash>Cristiano</Hash>
    <Line>
      <Unit>20</Unit>
      <Credit>20</Credit>
    </Line>
    <Document>
      <Tax>10</Tax>
      <Net>20</Net>
      <Gross>30</Gross>
    </Document>
  </Invoice>

  <Invoice>
    <Hash>Mario</Hash>
    <Line>
      <Unit>66</Unit>
      <Credit>66</Credit>
    </Line>
    <Document>
      <Tax>35</Tax>
      <Net>66</Net>
      <Gross>34</Gross>
    </Document>
  </Invoice>
</Sales>

  <Invoice>
    <Hash>Cristiano</Hash>
    <Line>
      <Unit>23</Unit>
      <Credit>23</Credit>
    </Line>
    <Document>
      <Tax>11</Tax>
      <Net>23</Net>
      <Gross>35</Gross>
    </Document>
  </Invoice>

  <Invoice>
    <Hash>Mario</Hash>
    <Line>
      <Unit>56</Unit>
      <Credit>56</Credit>
    </Line>
    <Document>
      <Tax>68</Tax>
      <Net>56</Net>
      <Gross>69</Gross>
    </Document>
  </Invoice>

  <Invoice>
    <Hash>Cristiano</Hash>
    <Line>
      <Unit>1</Unit>
      <Credit>1</Credit>
    </Line>
    <Document>
      <Tax>2</Tax>
      <Net>1</Net>
      <Gross>4</Gross>
    </Document>
  </Invoice>

  <Invoice>
    <Hash>Mario</Hash>
    <Line>
      <Unit>6</Unit>
      <Credit>6</Credit>
    </Line>
    <Document>
      <Tax>23</Tax>
      <Net>6</Net>
      <Gross>23</Gross>
    </Document>
  </Invoice>
</Sales>";


        //START Deleting Duplicates
        var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        var duplicates = (from req in doc.Descendants("Invoice")
                          group req by req.Descendants("Hash").First().Value
                              into g
                          where g.Count() > 1
                          select g.Skip(1)).SelectMany(elements => elements);
        foreach (var duplicate in duplicates)
        {
            duplicate.Remove();
        }
        //END Deleting Duplicates

        //Debug
        Console.WriteLine(doc);
 }
}
```

As you can see my XML has many `Invoice` entries but just two of them had different `Hash` one has `Cristiano` and another one has `Mario` at the moment my output is one of each.

Like This:

```
<Sales>
  <Invoice>
    <Hash>Cristiano</Hash>
    <Line>
      <Unit>20</Unit>
      <Credit>20</Credit>
    </Line>
    <Document>
      <Tax>10</Tax>
      <Net>20</Net>
      <Gross>30</Gross>
    </Document>
  </Invoice>

  <Invoice>
    <Hash>Mario</Hash>
    <Line>
      <Unit>66</Unit>
      <Credit>66</Credit>
    </Line>
    <Document>
      <Tax>35</Tax>
      <Net>66</Net>
      <Gross>34</Gross>
    </Document>
  </Invoice>
</Sales>
```

And I need one output that sums the values of `Unit`, `Credit`, `Tax`, `Net`, and `Gross`, where `Unit` and `Credit` must be the same as `Net`.

So Instead of what I'm getting I would need to have one output like this:

```
<Sales>
  <Invoice>
    <Hash>Cristiano</Hash>
    <Line>
      <Unit>44</Unit>
      <Credit>44</Credit>
    </Line>
    <Document>
      <Tax>33</Tax>
      <Net>44</Net>
      <Gross>69</Gross>
    </Document>
  </Invoice>

  <Invoice>
    <Hash>Mario</Hash>
    <Line>
      <Unit>128</Unit>
      <Credit>128</Credit>
    </Line>
    <Document>
      <Tax>126</Tax>
      <Net>128</Net>
      <Gross>129</Gross>
    </Document>
  </Invoice>
</Sales>
```

Is there any way that someone can help me with this?

Thanks and have a great day!

Comment: You didnt tried to solve that problem , theres no way ig i could help you :v

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method using xml linq.  It works, but may not be the least number of lines.  With linq, it really doesn't make a difference how compact the code is.  The execution time is the same.  So it is better to make the code understandable than to reduce the number of instructions.

Instead of deleting, I just took first element of each hash and modified.  Then replace original sales element with a new sales element consisting only the first hash.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<XElement> originalInvoices = doc.Descendants("Invoice").ToList();

            var groups = originalInvoices.GroupBy(x => (string)x.Element("Hash")).ToList();

            var finalInvoices = groups.Select(x => new {
                unit = x.Descendants("Unit").Sum(z => (int)z),
                credit = x.Descendants("Credit").Sum(z => (int)z),
                tax = x.Descendants("Tax").Sum(z => (int)z),
                net = x.Descendants("Net").Sum(z => (int)z),
                gross = x.Descendants("Gross").Sum(z => (int)z),
                first = x.First()
            }).ToList();

            foreach (var finalInvoice in finalInvoices)
            {
                finalInvoice.first.Element("Line").SetElementValue("Unit", finalInvoice.unit);
                finalInvoice.first.Element("Line").SetElementValue("Credit", finalInvoice.credit);
                finalInvoice.first.Element("Document").SetElementValue("Tax", finalInvoice.tax);
                finalInvoice.first.Element("Document").SetElementValue("Net", finalInvoice.net);
                finalInvoice.first.Element("Document").SetElementValue("Gross", finalInvoice.gross);
            }

            doc.Element("Sales").ReplaceWith(new XElement("Sales", finalInvoices.Select(x => x.first)));


        }
    }
}
```